# Automorphism group of a bipartite regular graph

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Showing an automorphism group of complete bipartite graph $K_{n,m}$ is easy. I'm wondering if there is an classification of automorphism groups of bipartite regular graphs. Did anyone heard something about that?

Comment: Frucht wrote a paper (in german) about how to construct graphs given an automorphism group: [Herstellung von Graphen mit vorgegebener
abstrakter Gruppe](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CM/CM_1939__6_/CM_1939__6__239_0/CM_1939__6__239_0.pdf)

Comment: There is no classification. In general regular bipartite graphs are no easier than arbitrary graphs.